# HTML5 CSS File won't be included

Tags: css, html

I tried to use a *css* stylesheet for my website here. The *css* file is names `main.css`, and is located in the same folder as my *html* file. However, everything I type into the *css* file won't add to the website.

Anyone have an idea why?

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Website</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="webcore">
    <header id="header">
        <h1>Welcome to Website</h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="section">
    </section>

    <aside id="news">
        <h1>News:</h1>
           News is fun!
    </aside>

    <footer id="footer">
        Footer.
    </footer>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe post you css file?

Comment: Silly question, but is main.css in the same folder as this HTML file?

Comment: Checked your server logs to see if the main.css hit is a 404? If not, did you check if the css is valid? A typo near the top of it would kill most of the directives

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to see if the request is failing and find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a slash in front of it like so.. /main.css

I don't know how your server is configured.. If the suggestion doesn't work please post a screenshot of the inspector showing the error of CSS file, or post a link to your site